# Get fields and attributes defined by thinking_sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

How can i get list of defined thinking_sphinx attributes and fields on a model?
In particular i want to check whether input attribute is defined for sphinx

example definition:

```
has store.name, :as => :store_name
```

i want something like `Model.sphinx_attributes.include? :store_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
Model.sphinx_indexes.collect { |index|
  index.attributes.collect &:unique_name
}.flatten.include?(:store_name)
```

Fields are much the same:

```
Model.sphinx_indexes.collect { |index|
  index.fields.collect &:unique_name
}
```

Before running either, it's good practice to run this first, to ensure the indexes are loaded:

```
Model.define_indexes
```

If they are already loaded, that method will do nothing.

Comment: Many thanks, that worked. Please add to answer that define_indexes should be used first( as you noticed here: [github issue 65](https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/issues/65) )

Comment: I remembered that just 20 minutes ago - good to see you figured it out anyway :)